# Check Failed: vec.size() == NDIMS (1 vs. 2) Aborted error in a RaspberryPi Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to train a Tensorflow Convolutional Neural Network on my RaspberryPi 3B. I get the following error:

```
2018-08-19 18:57:07.720022: F./tensorflow/core/util/bcast.h:111] Check failed:
vec.size() == NDIMS (1 vs. 2)
Aborted
```

Not sure what's going wrong, but here's the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os

image_height = 60
image_width = 1

image1_height = 15
image2_height = 1

model_name = "TensorflowCNN"


#Training Data Configuration

train_data = np.asarray(pd.read_csv("/media/pi/DISK_IMG/TrainingInput.csv", usecols=[1]))
lis = train_data.tolist()
lis = lis[0:60]
lis = [x[0].strip('[]\n,') for x in lis]
nlis = []
for i in lis:
    nlis.append(i.split())
for i in range(len(nlis)):
    nlis[i] = [float(x) for x in nlis[i] if x != "...,"]
nlis = [np.mean(x) for x in nlis]
train_data = np.asarray(nlis)

#Training Labels Configuration

train_labels = np.asarray(pd.read_csv("/media/pi/DISK_IMG/TrainingInput.csv", usecols=[2]))
mylist = train_labels.tolist()
mylist = mylist[0:60]
mylist = [x[0] for x in mylist]
index = 0
while index < len(mylist):
    if mylist[index] == "GravelTraining":
        mylist[index] = 1
    elif mylist[index] == "WaterTraining":
        mylist[index] = 2
    else:
        mylist[index] = 3

    index=index+1

train_labels = np.asarray(mylist)

#Validation Data Configuration

eval_data = np.asarray(pd.read_csv("/media/pi/DISK_IMG/TestingInput.csv", usecols=[1]))
List = eval_data.tolist()
List = List[0:15]
eval_data = np.asarray(List)

#Validation Labels Configuration

eval_labels = np.asarray(pd.read_csv("/media/pi/DISK_IMG/TestingInput.csv", usecols=[2]))
myList = eval_labels.tolist()
myList = myList[0:15]
index = 0
while index < len(myList):
    if myList[index] == "GravelTesting":
        myList[index] = 1
    elif myList[index] == "WaterTesting":
        myList[index] = 2
    else:
        myList[index] = 3

    index=index+1
eval_labels = np.asarray(myList)

category_names = list(map(str, range(3)))

#Processing and reshaping data

train_data = np.reshape(train_data, (-1, image_height, image_width, 1))
train_labels = np.reshape(train_labels, (-1, image_height, image_width, 1))

eval_data = np.reshape(eval_data, (-1, image1_height, image2_height, 1))
eval_labels = np.reshape(eval_labels, (-1, image1_height, image2_height, 1))


#CLASS FOR THE CONVOLUTIONAL NEURAL NETWORK


class ConvNet:

    def __init__(self, image_height, Image_width, num_classes, chan):

        self.input_layer = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [1,image_height, Image_width, chan], name = "inputs")

        conv_layer_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(self.input_layer, filters = 32, kernel_size = [5,5], padding = "same", activation = tf.nn.relu)
        pooling_layer_1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv_layer_1, pool_size = [2,1], strides = 1)

        flattened_pooling = tf.layers.flatten(pooling_layer_1)
        dense_layer = tf.layers.dense(flattened_pooling, 60, activation = tf.nn.relu)

        dropout = tf.layers.dropout(dense_layer, rate = 0.4, training = True)

        output_dense_layer = tf.layers.dense(dropout, num_classes)

        self.choice = tf.argmax(output_dense_layer, axis=1)
        self.probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(output_dense_layer)

        self.labels = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name="labels")
        self.accuracy, self.accuracy_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(self.labels, self.choice)

        one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(self.labels, dtype=tf.int32), depth=num_classes)
        self.loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels = one_hot_labels, logits=output_dense_layer)

        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-2)
        self.train_operation = optimizer.minimize(loss=self.loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

#Training process:variables

training_steps = 20000
batch_size = 60

path = "./" + model_name + "-cnn/"

load_checkpoint = False

tf.reset_default_graph()
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_labels))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=train_labels.shape[0])
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.repeat()

dataset_iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = dataset_iterator.get_next()

#Final initialization of Neural Network and Training Process

cnn = ConvNet(image_height, image_width, 1, 1)
print("milestone1")

saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=2)
print('milestone2')

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
print('milestone3')

#Training Loop For neural network

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print('milestone4')

    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(dataset_iterator.initializer)

    for step in range(training_steps):

        current_batch = sess.run(next_element)
        batch_inputs = current_batch[0]
        batch_labels = current_batch[1]
        print("milestone5")
        sess.run((cnn.train_operation, cnn.accuracy_op), feed_dict={cnn.input_layer:batch_inputs, cnn.labels:batch_labels})

        if step % 1 == 0 and step > 0:
            current_acc = sess.run(cnn.accuracy)
            print("Accuracy at step " + str(step) + ":" + str(current_acc))
            saver.save(sess, path + model_name, step)

    print("Saving final checkpoint for training session.")
    saver.save(sess, path + model_name, step)
```

I know it's long, but I would appreciate it if someone could let me know what's wrong with my program. There is no traceback.I'm getting the notification from Stack Overflow that my post is mostly code, but there's really not much more to say about the problem. Also, I have looked at many questions talking about this and have not found an answer in any of them that I can use. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know which line the error is occuring on?

Comment: Yup its the line  that says:  sess.run((cnn.train_operation, cnn.accuracy_op), feed_dict={cnn.input_layer:batch_inputs, cnn.labels:batch_labels})

Comment: but that's not very helpful because in the past all of my errors have traced back to that line.

Comment: This seems similar, do you have TF<1.8?: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/36979/invalid-argument-error-when-running-simple-convolutional-neural-network

Comment: i actually have 1.9

Comment: I have Tensorflow 1.9; also, I actually posted that question linked! I just posted it again on regular stack overflow to get more traffic.

Comment: Oh whoops, I missed that. Did you install Tensorflow using the instructions here? https://medium.com/tensorflow/tensorflow-1-9-officially-supports-the-raspberry-pi-b91669b0aa0 or https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_raspbian

Comment: I simply entered these two commands: `sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev` followed by `pip3 install tensorflow`

Comment: I am using python 3.5

Comment: I actually just took a look at the medium post you linked, and it's identical to the instructions I followed to install tensorflow; so that means that I followed the instructions in the first link